# Python 3.3.5 time module missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

When I try to import time I get : No module named time

I have tried other time modules(datetime and timeit) and they work fine. I decided to check my installation and I can't find time.py anywhere. I checked the Lib, Scripts, libs and include folders, but can't find it anywhere.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this? Maybe download the .py and put it in Lib myself?

I am using Python 3.3.5 with PyCharm IDE. Only extra scripts I've installed is EasyInstall and PRAW.

Comment: Please include the *full traceback* of your error. The `time` module is implemented in C, so you won't find it a `time.py` for it; it'll be called `time.dll` on Windows, instead.

Comment: When the module is compiled directly into the Python interpreter there is no separate file. The name should appear in `sys.builtin_module_names`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I never actually ran the code since my IDE said No module named time so I assumed I'd get compiler error. When I ran it to get traceback for Martijn it worked fine, guess PyCharm just doesn't detect dlls. Should I delete this question or will it have value for others?

Comment: @Vinc I suggest you post your comment as an answer. Perhaps edit the question to mention PyCharm as well.

Comment: sometimes known stdlib modules are not found due to [The name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap). Check that you do not use standard names for your modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried playing with virtualenv and a host of other things, but I eventually went to Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console, and in the "starting script" box, I added two lines:

```
sys.builtin_module_names.append('sys')
sys.builtin_module_names.append('time')
```

This got rid of errors I had with both sys and time.  Once I did that, I even get autocomplete for both of those modules... weird.

Answer (score 5):

The import does work. When PyCharm said No module named time, I assumed I would get a compiler error and started trying to fix it.

However when I eventually just ran the code it worked fine. I expect PyCharm doesn't detect the time module as it's a dll and not a py as noted by Martijn in the comments. This is on PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.4.

Comment: This also occurs for python 2.7.6 (or practically any version of Python I'm able to use as the interpreter) in PyCharm 4.0.4 (paid edition).  Compiles and runs fine, but PyCharm underlines it in red.